# Find all the Partitions of $X$. For each partition, show the corresponding equivalence relation as a subset $X \times X$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So $X = \{a,b,c\}$. So I know there are 5 partitions. They are:

$\{\{a\},\{b\} ,\{c\} \}$, $\{\{a,b\},\{c\} \}$, $\{\{a,c\},\{b\} \}$, $\{\{b,c\},\{a\} \}$ and $\{\{a,b,c\}\}$.

I don't really understand how to do the second part. I would know how to find the corresponding equivalence relation for $X$, but I'm not getting it for $X \times X$. Would this just be elements in the partitions grouped as ordered pairs?

Comment: A *relation on* $X$ is a *subset of* $X\times X$, but I must admit that the expression "show the equivalence relation for $X\times X$" looks rather strange to me. Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1099089/75923) can help.

Comment: Ah, I meant to say "as a subset" instead of "for" but I don't think it changes the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I think the link you provide is what I'm looking for! Thank you @drhab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the equivalence relation corresponding to a partition, two things are equivalent if they belong to the same cell (part, class, coset, whatever your book calls it, OK?) of the partition.

Look at the partition $\{\{a,c\},\{b\}\}$. Everything is equivalent to itself (of course), also $a$ and $c$ are equivalent to each other because then are both elements of $\{a,c\}$ which is one of the cells of the partition. So the equivalence relation, as a set of pairs, is
$$\{(a,a),(c,c),(a,c),(c,a),(b,b)\}$$
or maybe
$$\{\langle a,a\rangle,\langle c,c\rangle,\langle a,c\rangle,\langle c,a\rangle,\langle b,b\rangle\}$$
depending on what kind of brackets your book uses for ordered pairs.